# Chrome-extension developed using React not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I made a web app in React which i wanted to use as a chrome extension. But when I load the build folder and click on the icon I get a small white box and nothing else
Can someone please tell me what I did wrong.This is my manifest.json

```javascript
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "name",
  "description": "desc",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open App"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-OJ+UtHOO3C5swdxKPX5j37pdN56CatocDV87+5UMu9Q='; object-src 'self'",  "permissions": [
  ]
}
```

[image: this is what i get]

Comment: Right-click inside the popup, click "inspect", then investigate the console and DOM.

Comment: Console says DevTools failed to load Source Map

Comment: You can ignore that. Sounds like you output index.html is empty which means a problem with the compiler/bundler or its config. Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question.

Comment: I am using react-router .Does it have to do anything with that

Comment: AFAIK It should be configured to use hash mode because extensions are served as files, not as server-supplied pages. Look for existing answers on configuring the router for extensions.

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks